# How can I invert the selected items in multiple listboxes using only one for loop?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, for-loop, listboxitem

I am using three list boxes. I have to invert the selected items in all the list boxes using an invert button.

How can code it using only a single loop? There can be more than 3 list boxes as well.

Comment: It would help if you could motivate this a little further. It currently reads like a homework problem and doesn't give us any idea of why you need to accomplish the task with a single loop.

Answer (score 4):

Hi you could use this function to invert the selection for a given listbox.

```
    /* Windows ListBox
    public void InvertSelection(ListBox objLstbox)
    {
        if(objLstbox == null) return;

        for (int i = 0; i < objLstbox.Items.Count; i++)
            objLstbox.SetSelected(i, !objLstbox.GetSelected(i));
    }
    */

    //WebApp listbox
    public void InvertSelection(ListBox objLstbox)
    {
        if (objLstbox == null) return;

        for (int i = 0; i < objLstbox.Items.Count; i++)
            objLstbox.Items[i].Selected = !objLstbox.Items[i].Selected; 
    }

    private void btnInvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InvertSelection(listBox1);
        InvertSelection(listBox2);
        InvertSelection(listBox3);
    }
```

Comment: If only it were that simple... The `ListBox` control doesn't have a `Boolean`-type `Selected` property that you can simply invert. That means there's a whole lot more monkeying around to do than there should be; see my answer for details.

Comment: I had updated my pseudo code to working C# code. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Ah, and there you reveal my mistake! I had forgotten all about the `SetSelected` property! +1, this is a more elegant solution.

Comment: i am not able to use setselected and getselected function since the namespaces is not included in my VWD

Comment: @ady: The above code is from a tested and verified windows application. Are you referring to Windows application or WebApp ?

Comment: @Abraham: thanks a lot for helping me. i have modified set selected and get selected and used: if (objLstbox.Items[i].Selected == true) { objLstbox.Items[i].Selected = false; } else { objLstbox.Items[i].Selected = true;                                    it`s working absolutely well......Thanx again

Answer (score 0):

```
public void InvertSelection(ListBox objLstbox)
{
    if (objLstbox == null) return;

    for (int i = 0; i < objLstbox.Items.Count; i++)
        objLstbox.Items[i].Selected = !objLstbox.Items[i].Selected; 
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InvertSelection(ListBox1);
}
```

Comment: Seems like you are working on web application listbox control. I had updated the code snippet to contain both web as well as windows. You can use the "InvertSelection" method commented with "//WebApp listbox". This should work.

Answer (score 0):

I banged my head on this with the rest of you, and finally developed my own function for Inverting
Here's the VB.Net Answer:

```
Private Function InvertListBoxSelections(ByRef tempListBox As ListBox) As Integer
    Dim selectedind(tempListBox.SelectedItems.Count) As Integer
    Try
        For selind = 0 To tempListBox.SelectedItems.Count - 1
            selectedind.SetValue(tempListBox.Items.IndexOf(tempListBox.SelectedItems(selind)), selind)
        Next
        tempListBox.ClearSelected()
        For listitemIndex = 0 To tempListBox.Items.Count
            If Array.IndexOf(selectedind, listitemIndex) < 0 Then
                tempListBox.SetSelected(listitemIndex, True)
            End If
        Next
        Return 1
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return 0
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < listbox.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (listbox.SelectedItems.Contains(listbox.Items[i]))
            listbox.SetSelected(i, false);
        else
            listbox.SetSelected(i, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I got here and got confused by selection i'll leave this here.

This code inverts all checked items by using **.SetItemChecked** and **.GetItemChecked**:

```
private void ButtonInvertChecked_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox.Items.Count; i++)
        checkedListBox.SetItemChecked (i, !checkedListBox.GetItemChecked(i));
    }
```